# How can I display received file from request

Tags: node.js, api, express, request

When i do a requests to a API it's return a pdf file (if I visit URI from browser it's download file automatically). Bellow code's display a blank pdf file with the correct page number.

```
rp("URI")
    .then(data =>{
        res.contentType("application/pdf")
        res.send(data)
    })
    .catch(e =>{
        console.log(e)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your response header:

```
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="<your PDF file name>"
```